# Ctrl + U deletes whole line regardless of cursor position

Tags: terminal, osx, zsh, iterm2

I am learning terminal tips. In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8EUdia_kOE) tutorial, the guy says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> deletes everything from the cursor until the end of line. In my case, it always deletes the whole line. I am using `zsh` on macOS.

Comment: Actually, he says `Ctrl-U` kills to the beginning of the line. 2:40 into the video.

Comment: @JohanMyréen so how can I delete text from the course back to the beginning of the line ?

Comment: `Ctrl-U` deletes between the cursor and the beginning of the line. Of course, if the cursor is at the end of the line then the whole line is deleted.

Comment: @JohanMyréen that's not my case, even if the course in the middle of the line, Ctrl + U still deletes the whole line

Comment: The equivalent of `Ctrl-U` on zsh is `Ctrl-W`. This is why is "doesn't work" as expected. Found it on this askubuntu thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047849/clear-the-characters-before-the-current-cursor-position-in-zsh/1047874#1047874?newreg=52827d7cd9c64cdea63dc975e9b29d89

Answer (score 26):

First map the key binding by typing `bindkey \^U backward-kill-line`. Then test to see if this worked. If it works, make it permanent by adding the same line to an appropriate `zsh` RC file.

```
echo 'bindkey \^U backward-kill-line' >> ~/.zshrc
```

The [Z Shell Manual](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Modifying-Text), section 18.6.3, defines the "widgets," such as `backward-kill-line`.

Comment: it works! cool!

Answer (score 0):

if youre talking about GNU readline in the shell you will want to use Ctrl+K to kill to the endof the line.

Alternatively you can also use Alt+D to incremently kill on a breaking point

Edit: Just realized you're using zsh on Mac. The only server I haveusing zsh is in the cloud. Ill test real quick and verify.

Edit: Yes still works for me on Linux Ubuntu. Note that I installed zsh (and fish which is quite nice) on that machine about 2 weeks ago and never made a zshrc file. So there has been no special customizations as far as I can tell. Im guessing all these ZSH questions are in regards to what I heard was Apple leaving their ancient version of bash finally because they found something they can conveniently use